# How to visit attractions in Tasmania without a car?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, australia, tasmania

We will first arrive at the airport (HBA) in Tasmania, planning to go to the Sorell Fruit Farm, Marakoopa Cave and the Tasmanian Chairlifts.

We can't rent a car because we are still under 25, so how can we get there? What kind of public transportation is available? Is it convenient?

Comment: Make it a cycling holiday ;)

Comment: Bus lines are typically terrible - Hobart's "Metro" is bad enough, but intercity / regional lines have only a few routes a day.  I used to catch buses home to a town 35km away from Hobart after school, and if I missed the two (only two!) evening buses I was stranded.   Marakoopa Caves are in Mole Creek, the middle of nowhere, and while there are buses that go through Mole Creek itself on the way to Launceston, it's another 5km to the caves.  Basically, you need a car.  Luckily, as jpatokal says, you can rent if you're under 25.  Just expect to pay more.

Comment: The Launceston chairlift across Cataract Gorge is accessible by foot - it's in the city.  For the other two things you mention, you will need a car. Also, check out [Cradle Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cradle_Mountain) while you're in the centre - amazingly beautiful.  You may need to book ahead as I think there is a new plan where only a certain number of people are allowed to visit per year.

Comment: As an anecdote, we drove to Triabunna for a trip over to Maria Island (do this BTW) where we met a French girl who was basically stranded as there were no buses back to Hobart. They only went twice a week! We gave her a lift back in, but moral of the story is to try to get some wheels if you plan on travelling outside of Hobart/Launceston. Although all the bus timetables can be found online if you really MUST travel by bus. Just ensure to be well prepared and flexible.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to travel in Tasmania without a car -- but you *can* most definitely rent a car if you're under 25, although you'll need to pay a premium.  Check out [Redspot](https://www.redspot.com.au/), which serves both Hobart and Launceston airports and happily rents to drivers 21 and over, plus random small local hire companies (Google or the first hostel you stay in will have listings).

Answer (score 4):

If you're not uncomfortable with a little uncertainty, hitch-hiking is easy, and reliable almost anywhere in Tasmania. Folk are friendly and as a wilderness state it's been the custom to hitch into and out of bushwalking tracks for generations.

A modern fear and paranoia exists which will decry the suggestion, recommend against it, and possibly denounce me for suggesting it. But as one who has practiced it regularly and offers rides regularly, I can caution against lending these fear mongering conservative elements too much of your ear.

The real question is whether you are comfortable with uncertainty as you can't be sure of when you'll get places or if and how. Mostly hitch-hiking is very reliable and can get you from A to B faster than public transport, but if you're free and easy and open ended, sometimes you might end up changing your plans a little along the way, and accepting an invite to tag along with someone, or worse get stuck without a ride for longer than you like.

In Tasmania it's fair to say my average wait would be 15mins and the longest in a decade has been perhaps an hour or two.

Failing that try:
https://www.shareyourride.net/carpool/Australia

Answer (score 1):

Tasmania does have a city [bus network](http://www.metrotas.com.au/) to take you places. There are no trains. Taxis are also only available in the towns like Hobart. To travel cross-country, you can pick from a [multitude of bus](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g255096-s303/Tasmania%3aAustralia%3aPublic.Transportation.html) lines.